# How to select a child node that contains nodes from a parent XmlNode

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xmlnode

My XML is like this:

```
 <book genre="novel" style="hardcover">  
    <title>The Handmaid's Tale</title>  
    <author>  
      <first-name>Margaret</first-name>  
      <last-name>Atwood</last-name>  
    </author>  
    <price>19.95</price>  
  </book>  
  <book genre="novel" style="other">  
    <title>The Poisonwood Bible</title>  
    <author>  
      <first-name>Barbara</first-name>  
      <last-name>Kingsolver</last-name>  
    </author>  
    <price>11.99</price>  
  </book>
```

i am trying to select the "author" from the node "book"
i tried the below code, 
The code above navigates through "book" i can get the title and price, but i am not sure how to write the xpath for the author, i always get a null value as i tried different methods but non worked.

```
XmlDocument loadbooks = new XmlDocument();
loadbooks.LoadXml(responseXml);
XmlNodeList xmlBooks = loadbooks.GetElementsByTagName("book");


        if (xmlOrders != null)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode book in xmlBooks)
            {
    XmlNode xmlAuther = book.SelectSingleNode("book[@*]/author");
    XmlNode xmlAuther = book.SelectSingleNode("book/author");
    XmlNode xmlAuther = book.SelectSingleNode("author");
```

Please advise how to get the "author" single node from "book" node.

Comment: ignore :         if (xmlOrders != null)

Comment: You would need to select both first-name and last-name from author as those are the children of author element. `book/author/first-name`, `book/author/last-name`

Comment: although i don't prefer this method, i just tried it, but got null back.

Comment: oh okay, I just realized that your XML does not have a root. I tried enclosing your XML in "books" and then ran the XPATH like `/books/book/author/first-name/text()`, and it worked fine. Also please let us know why don't you prefer this method ?

Comment: because it's a response from another service, and the nodes might change.

Comment: is there anyway to use SelectSingleNode from the book using the author???

Comment: You xml is not well formed since it has an array at the root level.  You have to use XmlReader with an XmlReaderSettings that has property set : settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;